# Android Kotlin - Animation translationX ignores the distance and goes off screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swipe"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:rotation="26"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_swipe"
            app:tint="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using this code to make a swipe left animation:

```
swipe.animate().rotationBy(-30f).setDuration(1400)
    .translationX(-distance)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .start()
```

and then I just try to reset the position / swipe back with:

```
swipe.animate().rotationBy(30f).setDuration(1000)
    .translationX(distance)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .start()
```

but then the View goes to the right side until it's off the screen which means it ignores `distance`, why?

`distance` wasn't changed between animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix is to use `xBy` instead of `translationX`

if you will use `translationX` then it should be `translationX(-distance)` and `translationX(0)` to return to the same position

also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701657/setx-settranslationx-sety-and-settranslationy/33701994) that I think might be useful